# Child scope accessible in parent without 'ng-controller' directive set

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I don't understand how this is possible. Please clear this up for me. I am reading about the scope inheritance and, as far as I understood, we cannot access child's scope from the parent, right?

So I have this situation where I created a controller but forgot to set it in the template via `ng-controller` detective. But it still works. I never noticed it. So is this the expected behaviour or I am just missing something? I din't even know what parts of code to list here.

It is an ordinary controller

```
angular.module('Basal.tables')

.controller('ListTablesCtrl', function($scope, getTablesS) {
  $scope.tables = {};

  getTablesS.fetch(function (d){
    $scope.tables = d;
    });

});
```

... executed at location change

```
when('/tables', {
  templateUrl: '/views/tables/list-tables.html',
  controller: 'ListTablesCtrl'
}).
```

But there is no mention of the controller in the template.

```
<div class='frame' id='list-tables'>

<section class='title'> Tables </section>
<table>
  <tr ng-repeat='table in tables'>
    <td><input type='checkbox'></td>
    <td>{{ table.title }}</td>
    <td>{{ table.desc }}</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Everything works though. How is it possible to see the `tables` object here?
There is the top Main Controller set on the html body which means that it operates under this main controller in the template. But then how does it accesses child's scope?
Please explain if I am missing something silly.

Thanks.

Comment: the controller is added in the route ?  templateUrl: '/views/tables/list-tables.html',
  controller: 'ListTablesCtrl'

Comment: So if it is added in the route then it is not necessary to to add it in the template via `ng-controller`?

Comment: Yes, you got it. And if you had added a ng-controller inside the file, it would be a child controller to the controller mentioned in the route file. Same goes for nesting.

Comment: OK. I am getting there slowly )) So if I mention the controller in the route and then also set it in the template via `ng-controller` then the one in the template will be the child of the one in the route?? Even if they have the same name?

Comment: And yes Well do not do that. =]  that is like <ng-controller="FooCtrl"><ng-controller="FooCtrl"></div></div> dunno how it will handle but I would advice you not to do that.

Comment: OK. I won't do this. I promise. ) Thank you for clearing this up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular looks upwards for a controllers/method. 
Meaning if it is not in the current scope, it will look into the parent scope.

But in your case, you have have attached the controller in your route file.

`when('/tables', {
  templateUrl: '/views/tables/list-tables.html',
  controller: 'ListTablesCtrl'
})`

Comment: This is the correct answer. To elaborate further, at the route definition whenever you set the controller property and navigate to that route, angular will use the controller you have defined there. So, sure enough, you don't need to set the ng-controller directive in your template.

Comment: OK. I totally did not realize it. Thanks for clearing this up.